# In a makefile, how do I execute a command on each file name in variable?

Tags: c++, makefile

I know I am doing it wrong, but I can't figure out how to organize this makefile. I define my util source files, and use some functions to define the .o files from them here:

```
UTIL_SRC = utils/src/foo.cpp utils/src/bar.cpp utils/src/baz.cpp

UTIL_OBJS = $(patsubst utils/src/%.cpp,utils/obj/%.o,$(UTIL_SRC))
```

This is the target that I use these files for:

```
lib : lib/libutils.a

lib/libutils.a : $(UTIL_OBJS)
    rm -f lib/libutils.a
    ar -c -q lib/libutils.a $(UTIL_OBJS)
```

Then, when I get to the rule to compile these babies, I would love to just have one command that would iterate through each UTIL_OBJS file and each  UTIL_SRC file. Instead I have resorted to this monstrosity, which defeats the purpose of storing them in variables.

```
$(UTIL_OBJS) : $(UTIL_SRC)
    g++ $(UTIL_FLAGS) utils/src/foo.cpp -o utils/obj/foo.o
    g++ $(UTIL_FLAGS) utils/src/bar.cpp -o utils/obj/bar.o
    g++ $(UTIL_FLAGS) utils/src/baz.cpp -o utils/obj/baz.o
```

Can I condense this down to one line? How? Thanks, great ones!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's usually easier to work with implicit rules. There are a lot of predefined ones, where you'll only need to specify variables.

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=$(UTIL_FLAGS)
```

Then you need to define an executable, like this

```
myutil: $(UTIL_OBJS)
```

Since you're not storing your objects in the same directory, you'll need to specify a new implicit rule as well though (otherwise, we'd be done now).

```
utils/obj/%.o: utils/obj/%.cpp
```

% is a pattern-match, it'll match the same text on both left and right side, so this rule will make foo.o out of foo.cpp.
Try if that'll work without the command (it might have grabbed that from another rule, I'm not sure), otherwise let it say:

```
utils/obj/%.o: utils/obj/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

$@ is the target of the rule (e.g. foo.o), and $^ is all files on the right hand side.
I'm writing this off the top of my head, without the possibility to test it, so please let me know how it turned out.. :)

To make it even more elegant, you can include a dependency file

```
include .depend
```

If you're running GNU make, it'll try to make the .depend file if it can't find it (with old school make, you need to create it yourself first, it can be just a dummy though, if you'd like to manage it through the makefile)

```
.depend: $(UTIL_SRC)
    $(CXX) -MM -o $@ $^
```

The dependency file will contain lines for each .cpp file, telling make what header files it needs, which will allow make to recompile the necessary files when you change something. This doesn't help with your original question though, just thought it might come in handy.

**EDIT:**
As a response to your edit. You could probably drop the commands for creating the .a-file as well, that too is already available as an implicit rule. Not sure exactly how it works though, haven't used it much. I do know that there are a bunch of quirks in make for dealing with .a(rchive?)-files.

Comment: Indeed, pattern rules are the way to go.

Comment: I tried just the pattern rule without the command and it didn't work. However, explicitly defining the command worked. Does the pattern rule cause make to search for utils/src/%.cpp?

Comment: No, it won't search for .cpp files, it'll look at what utils/obj/%.o files it needs, and this rule fits, so it'll make it from utils/src/%.cpp. It kind of works itself backwards. The trigger is the line `myutil: $(UTIL_OBJS)` where you tell it what .o files you want. And in this case, all of them are in utils/obj/

Comment: So if I understand it right, make sees the dependancy on $(UTIL_OBJS) and notices that there is a rule for compiling files that should look like utils/obj/%.o. It then uses the pattern rule for each thing in $(UTIL_OBJS) to generate the .o files. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, make sees dependencies to all the .o-files in the $(UTIL_OBJS), and tries to make each one. For each .o-file in turn, it determines that the utils/obj/%.o rule fits best, and uses that to make the .o-file (if necessary, i.e. the cpp-file is newer than the o-file, or the o-file doesn't exist).

Comment: "It's usually easier to work with implicit rules." ... "Try if that'll work without the command (it might have grabbed that from another rule, I'm not sure), ".
That's exactly why it's NOT easier to work with implicit rules.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use this:

```
$(UTIL_OBJS) : $(UTIL_SRC)
    g++ $(UTIL_FLAGS) $(@ : .o = .cpp)  -o $@
```

again, I'm not quite sure... especialy about the $(@ : .cpp = .o) part

Comment: What do all of these magic symbols mean? It looks like Perl on crack.

Comment: $@ is the target of the rule, : tells it to replace a suffix

Comment: Note: `$(@ : .o = .cpp)` doesn't work because of the spaces, it needs to be `$(@:.o=.cpp)` (At least for me)